# Protocols, Structs, but no concrete type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Ok I have a protocol called `Environment`

```
protocol Environment {
  var rootURL: String {get}
}
```

Then two structs:

```
struct Production: Environment {
  var rootURL = "www.api.mybackend.com/v1"
}

struct Development: Environment {
  var rootURL = "www.api.mydevelopmentbackend.com/v1"
}
```

A settings object with a function that retrieves the environment:

```
class Settings {
  func getEnvironment<T>() -> T where T: Environment {
    let environmentRaw = self.retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore()
    switch environmentRaw {
    case 0:
        return Development() as! T
    case 1:
        return Production() as! T
    default:
        return Development() as! T
    }
  }

  func retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore() -> Int {
    //Realm, SQLLite, Core Date, I don't really care for this example. 
    //Let's just say it defaults to returning 1
  }
}
```

I really want to keep moving in a [Protocol Oriented Programming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/) direction but now when I call this function on a settings object and try to use the `rootURL` property the compiler complains it can't figure out the type. So, to better my understanding and to maybe find a solution:

1) Why does it care about the type if I am accessing a property defined by a protocol that at the very least it knows the returning type conforms to?

2) Structs don't have inheritance. Should I define a base class and forget about generics?

3) Can I make my `getEnvironment` function better? I don't like force casting, it seems like a code smell.

4) Am I even using generics correctly here?

EDIT 1:

To be clear, I want one function that returns a struct that I know will have this property.

Comment: `UEEnvironment` and `Environment` are different types, right?

Comment: Yeah, just fixed it. Copy and paste error

Comment: You said “when I call this function on a settings object and try to use the rootURL property the compiler complains it can't figure out the type”. Copy the code that calls the function, and paste it into the question. Also copy the compiler error message and paste it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I even using generics correctly here?

No, I don't think so. You are saying that `getEnvironment` will return `T` which can be any type that the client code specifies, as long as it implements `Environment`. However, the implementation of the method doesn't do this. It will only return two kinds of `Environment`s, and which type it returns is not determined by the client code. The type returned depends on what `retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore` returns. Hence, generics is not suitable in this case.

Since the type of environment it returns is decided by the implementation of the method, instead of the client code, you should make use of polymorphism here - make it return an `Environment` instead:

```
  func getEnvironment() -> Environment {
    let environmentRaw = self.retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore()
    switch environmentRaw {
    case 0:
        return Development()
    case 1:
        return Production()
    default:
        return Development()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you sweeper! Exactly the piece I am missing. I did not know that a protocol can be the return type of a function.

Comment: This is the solution to this question.

Answer (score 3):

> I really want to keep moving in a Protocol Oriented Programming direction

I suggest instead you try to move in a clear, understandable code direction, regardless of what the trendy orientation is.

Here's your function declaration:

func getEnvironment() -> T where T: Environment

This says that `getEnvironment()` will return an object of some type `T`, where `T` is deduced **at compile time** based on the code that calls `getEnvironment()`.

What types could `T` be? It could be either `Production` or `Development`. For example, you could write:

```
let e: Production = Settings().getEnvironment()
```

This lets the compiler deduce that `getEnvironment()` returns a `Production` (which is an `Environment`) at this call site.

But there's a problem: `getEnvironment()` might try to return a `Development` anyway, based on the random number generator inside `retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore`. Then you'll get a crash **at run time** when it fails to cast `Development` to `Production`.

Why do you think `getEnvironment()` needs to be generic at all? Based on the code in your question, it shouldn't be.

```
import Foundation

protocol Environment {
    var rootURL: String {get}
}

struct Production: Environment {
    var rootURL = "www.api.mybackend.com/v1"
}

struct Development: Environment {
    var rootURL = "www.api.mydevelopmentbackend.com/v1"
}

class Settings {
    func getEnvironment() -> Environment {
        let environmentRaw = self.retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore()
        switch environmentRaw {
        case 1: return Production()
        default: return Development()
        }
    }

    func retreiveEnvironmentFromLocalStore() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random())
    }
}


let settings = Settings()
let e = settings.getEnvironment()
```

---

Style note: the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#strive-for-fluent-usage) advise us to

> - Name functions and methods according to their side-effects
>
>   - Those without side-effects should read as noun phrases, e.g. `x.distance(to: y), i.successor()`.

Unless the methods in `Settings` have important side effects, better names would be `environment()` and `rawEnvironmentFromLocalStore()`.